# Bulidozer runs into an error `missing foo.jar file`

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

After I fixed the problem with aidl, I ran into another problem

```
...
# Package the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.33', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 714, in build_package
        pattern))
SystemError: Failed to find jar file: /home/ivan/Downloads/kivy/foo.jar
```

where can I get this file, or what else should I do to fix this?

this is my buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = My Application

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1


Android specific


# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
#fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

#(list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

#(int) Android API to use
android.api = 19

#(int) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 9

#(int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 20

#(str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 9c

#(bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
android.private_storage = True

#(str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path =

#(str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path =

#(str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ant_path =

#(bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
android.ouya.category = APP

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 1

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

While I was installing stuff, I was logged in as root, but then I started `buildozer init` and  `buildozer android debug deploy run` as non-root since it gave me warnings I should not run it as root

Comment: can you post your **buildozer.spec** file? and do tell me are you logged in as root or not?

Comment: @Mandy8055 I updated the post with my buildozer.spec file. No, I am not logged as root as I run stuff, but when I was installing buildozer and aidl amd ./android stuff in the folder U told me about, I logged in as root for convenience.

Comment: @Mandy8055 then why they do not recommend it? or did U mistype and you intended to say "I do not recommend"?

Comment: Okay as far as I can see; you have to comment this line:`android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar`

Comment: I mistyped. Sorry for that? Try this I think it might help because this problem is rare

Comment: @Mandy8055 ooh, I already started running that stuff as root lol

Comment: Ya; I would not recommend you to log in as root because it would help you to sort out much problems which would occur to you(may be in future)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152934/discussion-between-nihao92-and-mandy8055).

Answer (score 0):

You should only comment these strings:

```
#(list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
#their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
#down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
#OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar
```